# Derivative of ReLU

Tags: pytorch

I'm learning PyTorch. Here is the first example in official tutorial. I got two questions, as shown in the block below,

a) I understand that derivative of a ReLU function is 0 when x < 0 and 1 when x > 0. Is that right? But the code seems to keep the x > 0 part unchanged and set x < 0 part to 0. Why is that?

b) Why transpose, i.e. x.T.mm(grad_h)? A transpose does't seem needed to me. I'm just confused. Thanks,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import torch


dtype = torch.float
device = torch.device("cpu")
# device = torch.device("cuda:0") # Uncomment this to run on GPU

# N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
# H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

# Create random input and output data
x = torch.randn(N, D_in, device=device, dtype=dtype)
y = torch.randn(N, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)

# Randomly initialize weights
w1 = torch.randn(D_in, H, device=device, dtype=dtype)
w2 = torch.randn(H, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)

learning_rate = 1e-6
for t in range(500):
    # Forward pass: compute predicted y
    h = x.mm(w1)
    h_relu = h.clamp(min=0)
    y_pred = h_relu.mm(w2)

    # Compute and print loss
    loss = (y_pred - y).pow(2).sum().item()
    print(t, loss)

    # Backprop to compute gradients of w1 and w2 with respect to loss
    grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y)
    grad_w2 = h_relu.t().mm(grad_y_pred)
    grad_h_relu = grad_y_pred.mm(w2.t())
```

> ```
>     grad_h = grad_h_relu.clone()
>     grad_h[h < 0] = 0
>     grad_w1 = x.t().mm(grad_h)
> ```

```
    # Update weights using gradient descent
    w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
    w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not programming related, it is math related, the fact that there is some code is secondary as the one up voted answer proves.

Answer (score 1):

1- It is true that derivative of a ReLU function is 0 when x < 0 and 1 when x > 0. But notice that gradient is flowing from output of the function to all the way back to h. When you get all the way back to calculate `grad_h`, it is calculated as:

```
grad_h = derivative of ReLu(x) * incoming gradient
```

As you said exactly, derivative of ReLu function is 1 so grad_h is just equal to incoming gradient.

2- Size of the x matrix is 64x1000 and grad_h matrix is 64x100. It is obvious that you can not directly multiply x with grad_h and you need to take transpose of x to get appropriate dimensions.